# How can one debt-finance a corporate takeover and then transfer debt to the company?

Tags: loans, debt, corporation, corporate-acquisition

I'm reading about the [Glazer family's takover of soccer club Manchester United](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glazer_ownership_of_Manchester_United) nearly two decades ago. They apparently debt-financed their takeover, borrowing hundreds of millions of pounds, and some of that debt was transferred to the club. As a result, the club went into debt for the first time since 1931.

> The debt taken on by the Glazers to finance the takeover was split between the club and the family; between £265 million and £275 million was secured against Manchester United's assets, putting the club into debt for the first time since James Gibson saved them in 1931. This loan was provided by three New York hedge funds: Citadel, Och-Ziff Capital Management and Perry Capital. The total amount was £660 million, on which interest payments came to £62 million a year.

This doesn't make sense to me. What is stopping me from borrowing $2.65 billion (the current market capitalization of the club), becoming the owner, transferring the full debt to the club, and then letting the club go bankrupt? If the answer is "nothing", does that mean I get to manipulate the English Premier League rankings by selectively messing with teams' finances?

Comment: This is not a question about _personal_ finance (despite the query at the end which personalizes it) and I am voting to close it.

Comment: Deliberately bankrupting a company by overloading it with unrelated debt is illegal in most jurisdictions. Otherwise everybody would just get rid of their debt by transferring it to a subdivision ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This doesn't make sense to me. What is stopping me from borrowing
> $2.65 billion...?

I believe you will find the biggest hurdle will be finding someone to loan you the $2.65B so you can do this.  Any lender is going to want to know exactly how they are going to be repaid and your plan of "transfer and file bankruptcy" is not going to sell well.